# MSBuild svn xml log export

Tags: svn, msbuild

I have this MSBuild file, which compresses my javascript, css and changes the version number to match the SVN revision number:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="CssCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="..\..\_Shared\YuiCompressor-2.3.0.0\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="JavaScriptCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="..\..\_Shared\YuiCompressor-2.3.0.0\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\_Shared\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

  <Target Name="Minify" Condition="'$(ConfigurationName)' == 'Release'">

    <!-- css and js compression using yui -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <CssFiles Include="$(SourceLocation)../content/*.css" Exclude="../content/*.min.css" />
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="$(SourceLocation)../scripts/*.js" Exclude="../*.min.js" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <CssCompressorTask
      SourceFiles="%(CssFiles.Identity)" 
      DeleteSourceFiles="false"
      OutputFile="%(CssFiles.RelativeDir)%(CssFiles.Filename).min.css"
      CompressionType="Standard"
      LoggingType="Info"
      PreserveComments="false"
      LineBreakPosition="-1"
      />

    <JavaScriptCompressorTask
      SourceFiles="%(JavaScriptFiles.Identity)"
      DeleteSourceFiles="false"
      OutputFile="%(JavaScriptFiles.RelativeDir)\min\%(JavaScriptFiles.Filename).min.js"
      CompressionType="Standard"
      ObfuscateJavaScript="True"
      PreserveAllSemicolons="False"
      DisableOptimizations="No"
      EncodingType="Default"
      LineBreakPosition="-1"
      LoggingType="Info"
      ThreadCulture="en-gb"
      IsEvalIgnored="false"
      />

    <!-- version numbering from subversion -->
    <SvnVersion LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" ToolPath="C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin">
      <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
    </SvnVersion>

    <FileUpdate Files="..\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
                Regex="(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(.+)"
                ReplacementText="$1.$2.$(Revision).$4" />

  </Target>
```

How do I change this to get an SVN XML log file generated as well so i can create release notes.

I have the svn the command: svn log --xml

Comment: Wouldn't you need a base revision for the the last "release"? The log for the last commit probably wouldn't cover all the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added

```
<Exec Command="svn log ..\properties\assemblyinfo.cs --xml > ..\releasenotes.xml"/>
```

Seems to do the trick.